# If $f(x-3) = x^2$, $f(x) = (x+3)^2$?

Tags: functions

I was wondering suppose you have $f(x-3) = x^2$. Is it correct to say that $f(x) = f(x-3 +3 ) = (x+3)^2$. If so, why or why not? Why can we say that if $g(x) = x^2 + x$, then $g(x+2) = (x+2)^2 + (x+2)$ but not the other way around?

Comment: Is $f(x) = f(x-3 +3 ) = (x+3)$ a typing mistake?  Do you mean $f(x) = f(x-3 +3 ) = (x+3)^2$?

Comment: I fixed the typo that @badjohn suggested; and yes, you can do that. $x$ is merely a number, and so is $x-3$ or $x+2$.

Comment: In your case, the functions are presumably defined on the whole of $\Bbb{R}$.  If they were not then you would need to adjust the domain.  Consder $f(x - 3) = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Let $y=x-3$, then $x=y+3$, so $f(x-3)=x^2 \implies f(y)=(y+3)^2$. The name of the variable does not matter, so we can switch back to x: $f(x)=(x+3)^2$.

Comment: You better write $f(x)=f((x+3)-3)=(x+3)^2$.

Comment: I just heard or read somewhere that if $f(x+3) = x^2-4x-5$ , then you can't say that $f(x) = (x-3)^2 - 4(x-3) -5$.

Comment: BTW, I'd write your second equation as $f(x)=f((x+3)-3)=(x+3)^2$ - that's clearer IMO.

Comment: Where did you hear or read that? It's wrong.

Comment: @Nick Exactly my point. I don't understand why we can say that $f(x) = f(x-3 +3 ) = (x+3)^2$ but not what I mentioned in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret 
$f(x-3) = x^2$
as composition
$f \circ u$
where $u(x) = x - 3$.

In this case $x = u + 3$ and $f(u) = x^2 = (u+3)^2$ or $f(x) = (x + 3)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

In

$$f(x-3)=x^2$$ you can substitute $x-3$ with $x$, provided you do it with all occurrences of $x$. To make it possible, we rewrite

$$f(x-3)=((x-3)+3)^2.$$

Then after substitution,

$$f(x)=(x+3)^2.$$